# Providing anonymity while retaining data access for users

Tags: database, anonymous

Suppose I had two tables, one contained user login information, (id, email, hashed_password, name, etc) the other contained personal information (id, gender, age, favourite colour, etc)

I want a user who logs in to be able to access their personal information, but no one else to be able to link a user's personal information back to the user.

One solution I am considering is having each id of the personal information table be an encrypted version of the corresponding id in the login table where the encryption key is the user password.

I realise this would lead to the link between rows being severed if the user forgot their password. Are there any better solutions to this problem? Or can you point out any flaws in my solution that I haven't noticed?

Comment: Don't know which database you are talking about, but I think all the modern databases are now providing built-in support for Data Encryption.